# how to random 3 arrays eclipse android

Tags: random

I have 3 arrays, they are connected to each other

`string []a = {"a","b","c"};
string []b = {"1","2","3"};
string []c = {"a1","b2","c3"};`

my question, how to random that?
because, I have a game like quiz, so I want the question shuffling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `boolean[] d` of the same size as the other arrays initialised to `true`. Pick a random number between `0 to length of array - 1`. Keep on marking `false` in the boolean array to all those questions that you have asked.